# Magic Mouse Left-Click Intermittently Doesn't Work Sometimes in Chrome

Tags: macos, mouse

I'm running macOS Sierra. Lately, my left mouse click intermittently doesn't work in Chrome. I'll. I have to click a few times for the click to register.

It's worst on the Magic Mouse, but also happens on the Magic Mouse 1.

I tried the following:

1. Restarting
2. Cleaning surfaces of Mouse
3. Reset PRAM
4. Re-pairing the Mouse
5. Make sure batteries are fully charged

At first I didn't know if it was the mouse, OS, or a specific app. Now I am relatively sure that the problem exists in Chrome.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you happen to have the window manager app Magnet running? Or perhaps BetterTouchTool? Both of those seem to be problematic with the latest versions of chrome. Check this out: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/2s3ejYEm_QY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem only happens while [Magnet](http://magnet.crowdcafe.com) is running:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/03EmKuDuw5c;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3AStable%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false

I have contacted Magnet and asked fi they will release a fix to solve this problem. If they do, I'll post an update here.